# Div scrolling top

Tags: jquery, scroll

In the following example I have a scrolling box on the right. I want it stopped just above the foot and not rode in it.
http://piotr-m.pl/projekty/skladacze/espace/detal.html

```
        var offset = jQuery('aside').offset();  

    $(window).scroll(function () {  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // check the visible top of the browser  
    if (offset.top<scrollTop) 
        $('aside').addClass('fixed').css('top', scrollTop-250); 
    else 
        $('aside').removeClass('fixed');  
    });
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: have you tried changing the `z-index` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the footer z-index to -1

like this

```
#footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
background: white;
}
```

Comment: Approx. Only I want the div to the right of the stop in front of fotterem not moved on.